# How to add and update in one api in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

I am trying to add and update using the same API, currently, I can add but I am not clear about how to update using the same API.

I am adding folders against id and my body response looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "folder_detail": [1,3,4]
}
```

I can add folders with id 1,3 and 4 against id 2 but next time when I hit the same API with folder[1,3,5]  it should update folders details not should add again, I can do that by making separate API but I want to do that in one API.

My Controller code:

```
 try {

            $folder = Doctor::where('id', $request->get('id'))->first();
            $folder->doctor()->attach($request->get('folder_detail', []));

            DB::commit();

            return response([
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'Folder detail added',
            ], 200);

        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            DB::rollback();
            return response([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => __('messages.validation_errors'),
                'errors' => $ex->getMessage(),
            ], 500);
        }
    }

    public function doctor()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Folder', 'folder_details');
    }
```

Your help will be highly appreciated?

Comment: I cannot give a thorough explanation with a code example, but from your code I see the first line only retrieves the first folder, rather than all of them. You need to get all the folders stored for the id, match them with the folder details provided and update or add whenever suitable.

Comment: can you edit your explanation in my code?

Comment: see Brendan's answer below

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after our back and forth in the comments I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$folders = $request->get('folder_detail', []);

foreach($folders as $folder) {
    $record = Folder::firstOrNew(['id', $folder]);
    $record->doctor_id = $request->id;

   // You can add your own records here, or use the 'fill' function
}
```

So, this way, you loop through all your folders. Check if the folder with the specific ID already exists, if it does not, it creates a new one. The doctor is linked through the doctor_id on your record.

Answer (score 0):

Find record if exist then update otherwise create

```
$post = $request->all();

$doctor = Doctor::find($post['id']);

if($doctor){
    $doctor->update([
        //your data for update doctor model
    ]);

    //remove old folders which is related with this doctor
    Folder::where('doctor_id', $doctor->id)->delete();

    //add current data of folder
    if(!empty($post['folder_detail'])){
        foreach($post['folder_detail'] as $folder){
            Folder::create([
                'doctor_id' => $doctor->id,
                'folder_detail' => $folder
            ]);
        }
    }

    //return your response here

} else {
    $doctor = Doctor::create([
        //data for create doctore
    ]);

    //add current data of folder
    if(!empty($post['folder_detail'])){
        foreach($post['folder_detail'] as $folder){
            Folder::create([
                'doctor_id' => $doctor->id,
                'folder_detail' => $folder
            ]);
        }
    }

    //return your response here
}
```